# Excel similarities between columns, with adjacent values

Tags: excel, exception, excel-2010

I've got four columns of data that I'm interested in. A, with names, B with values, C with names, and D with values. I'd like to generate three more columns E, F, G. E will have the overlap in names between A and C, F will have the associated value in B and G will have the associated value from D. Any luck?

Comment: What do you mean by "the overlap in names"?  Only return a value if the names are similar?  Show us what you've tried.  It sounds like VLOOKUPs would help your columns F and G.

Comment: By overlap I mean, if a value in A shows up in C, then record its associated value in B and D in columns F and G. Sorry for not explaining that better.

Comment: That makes sense.  So what goes in column E?

Answer (score 0):

This may be too basic, but if you put these three formulas in you should get the desired result, assuming you dont have duplicates in A or C.  These IF statements will return a blank when there is no result (no match in A and C) and you can double click to copy them down the whole sheet.

```
    Column E =IF(A2=C2,A2,"")
    Column F =IF(E2=A2,B2,"")
    Column G =IF(E2=C2,D2,"")
```